# Jquery not send values when form is submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using this component: https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input

and I have this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#tags_3').tagsInput({
                    width: 'auto',
                    'delimiter': [',', ';'],
                    autocomplete_url: '{{ pageTemplate.pageHeader.webUrl }}/addPhoto/tags',
                    'onChange': function () {
                        var text = $('.tagsinput').val();
                        alert($('#tags_3').tagsInput('items'));
                        $("#tags_3").val($('#tags_3_tagsinput').val());
                    }
                });

            });

        </script>

    <form method="post" name="contactformXX" class="form validate clearfix validate-form"
                              action="bla.html" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <textarea id="tags_3" class="form-control kontakt_input tags" rows="4" id="slowa_kluczowe1"
                                          name="keywords" placeholder="Wpisz słowa kluczowe"></textarea>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger kontakt_button margin_50 button_mop_r_poczta">save</button>
    </form>
```

When I click the "save" button, the data from the "keywords" text is not visible in the $ _POST variable in PHP.

How to fix it?

http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/test/index.php - here is preview

Comment: there are two ids for textarea .remove those

Comment: I'm correct it http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/test/index.php - but it's not help :(

Comment: i just copy this code and paste, and it works for me, i can see keywords in post, under network tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `<input>` instead of `<textarea>`. This plugin only works with `<input>`s. Also, you should remove the `onChange` callback – `#tags_3_tagsinput` is not an input, so it doesn't have a value, so the `.val()` method returns `''`.

Comment: I try with this: <input type="text" id="tags_3" class="form-control kontakt_input tags" rows="4" id="slowa_kluczowe1"
                                      name="tags" placeholder="Wpisz słowa kluczowe*" value=""> - but it's not working

Comment: @traekdjf Remove the `onChange` callback.

Comment: thank you :) It's working now :) Czy wiesz może dlaczego nie działa autocomplete? autocomplete_url: 'tags.html' ? :)

Comment: @traekdjf `tags.html` powinien zwracać tablicę elementów, np. `["inky", "pinky", "blinky", "clyde"]`.

Comment: super, działa :) dziękuje :)